# Pandas messing up the date column on DataFrame.from_csv

Tags: python, date, csv, pandas

I'm using Python 3.4.0 with pandas==0.16.2. I have soccer team results in CSV files that have the following columns: date, at, goals.scored, goals.lost, result. The 'at' column can have one of the three values (H, A, N) which indicate whether the game took place at team's home stadium, away or at a neutral place respectively. Here's the head of one such file:

```
date,at,goals.scored,goals.lost,result
16/09/2014,A,0,2,2
01/10/2014,H,4,1,1
22/10/2014,A,2,1,1
04/11/2014,H,3,3,0
26/11/2014,H,2,0,1
09/12/2014,A,4,1,1
25/02/2015,H,1,3,2
17/03/2015,A,2,0,1
19/08/2014,A,0,0,0
```

When I load this file into pandas.DataFrame in the usual way:

```
import pandas as pd
aTeam = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("teamA-results.csv")
```

the first two columns 'date' and 'at' seem to be treated as one and I get a malformed data frame like this one:

```
aTeam.dtypes

at              object
goals.scored     int64
goals.lost       int64
result           int64
dtype: object

aTeam

    at  goals.scored    goals.lost  result
date                
2014-09-16  A   0   2   2
2014-01-10  H   4   1   1
2014-10-22  A   2   1   1
2014-04-11  H   3   3   0
2014-11-26  H   2   0   1
...
```

The code block does not clearly reflect the corruption, so I attached the screenshot from the Jupyter notebook:

[image: date+at columns corruption after csv_read]

As you can see 'date' and 'at' columns seemed to be treated as one column of object type:

```
aTeam['at']

date
2014-09-16    A
2014-01-10    H
2014-10-22    A
2014-04-11    H
2014-11-26    H
2014-09-12    A
```

Initially I thought the lack of quotes around the date was causing this problem, so I added those, but it did not help at all, so then I en-quoted all the values in the 'at' column which still did not solve the problem. I tried single and double quotes in the CSV file. Interestingly using no quotes or double quotes around the values in 'date' and 'at' produced the same results as you could see above. Single quotes were interpreted as parts of the value in the 'at' column, but not in the date column:

[image]

Adding the `parse_dates=True` param did not have any effect on the data frame.

I did not have such issues when I was working with these CSV files in R. I will appreciate any help on this one.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, 1. don't use `from_csv` it's not being updated anymore, use `pandas.read_csv`, 2. the `index_col` param for `from_csv` is defaulted to `index_col=0` this is why the first column is being treated as the index. When I load your data I get date as the index not 'date' and 'at'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no problem here (using Python 2.7, Pandas 16.2).  I used the text you pasted and created a .csv file on my desktop and loaded it in Pandas using two methods

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
b = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('test.csv')

>>>a
         date at  goals.scored  goals.lost  result
0  16/09/2014  A             0           2       2
1  01/10/2014  H             4           1       1
2  22/10/2014  A             2           1       1
3  04/11/2014  H             3           3       0
4  26/11/2014  H             2           0       1
5  09/12/2014  A             4           1       1
6  25/02/2015  H             1           3       2
7  17/03/2015  A             2           0       1
8  19/08/2014  A             0           0       0


>>>b
           at  goals.scored  goals.lost  result
date                                           
2014-09-16  A             0           2       2
2014-01-10  H             4           1       1
2014-10-22  A             2           1       1
2014-04-11  H             3           3       0
2014-11-26  H             2           0       1
2014-09-12  A             4           1       1
2015-02-25  H             1           3       2
2015-03-17  A             2           0       1
2014-08-19  A             0           0       0
```

You can see the different behavior between the read_csv and from_csv commands in how the index is handled.  However, I do not see anything like the problem you mentioned.  You could always try further defining the read_csv parameters, though I doubt that will make a substantial difference.

Could you confirm that your date and "at" columns are being smashed together by querying the dataframe via aTeam['at'] and see what that yields?

Comment: I added the output of aTeam['at'] to the post.

Comment: It looks like there is no problem here.  Your index has been named "date", which is why "date" is showing up when you query aTeam['at'], but that is just the index.  Per EdChum's advice, switch to read_csv as shown in example "a" above.  I think if you do a aTeam.describe() you will see that everything is in order.

Comment: Your explanation seems correct and most likely that is why adding index_col=None to from_csv solved the problem.

Comment: And why there is a down vote for my answer I will never know.  SO can be a mystery to me sometimes...just saying.

Comment: @tknepp That -1 was not from me.

Comment: I figured it wasn't.  It was probably somebody just browsing through and didn't read the question/answer thoroughly.  It happens from time to time.  While it would be nice if people would comment when casting a down vote, such is life.  I can't be too upset over a down vote now and then.

Answer (score 2):

I can replicate your issue using from_csv,the issue is it uses  col 0 as the index so passing `index_col=None` would work:

**index_col** : *int or sequence, default 0*

> Column to use for index. If a sequence is given, a MultiIndex is used. Different default from read_table

```
import pandas as pd
aTeam = pd.DataFrame().from_csv("in.csv",index_col=None)
```

Output:

```
         date at  goals.scored  goals.lost  result
0  16/09/2014  A             0           2       2
1  01/10/2014  H             4           1       1
2  22/10/2014  A             2           1       1
3  04/11/2014  H             3           3       0
4  26/11/2014  H             2           0       1
5  09/12/2014  A             4           1       1
6  25/02/2015  H             1           3       2
7  17/03/2015  A             2           0       1
8  19/08/2014  A             0           0       0
```

Odr using .[read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) works correctly  and is what you probably wanted based on the fact you were trying `quotechar` which is a valid arg:

```
import pandas as pd


aTeam = pd.read_csv("in.csv")
```

Output:

```
         date at  goals.scored  goals.lost  result
0  16/09/2014  A             0           2       2
1  01/10/2014  H             4           1       1
2  22/10/2014  A             2           1       1
3  04/11/2014  H             3           3       0
4  26/11/2014  H             2           0       1
5  09/12/2014  A             4           1       1
6  25/02/2015  H             1           3       2
7  17/03/2015  A             2           0       1
8  19/08/2014  A             0           0       0
```

Comment: @Padraig I removed the references to the read_csv doc page as non relevant - it was my bad to include it.

Comment: @Padraig: All right! index_col=None solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Padraic But even adding index_col=None does not solve the issue.  I don't believe his columns were getting smashed together as claimed, rather the index was being named "date" when loaded with the from_csv and he was getting confused.  Can you confirm that the columns are actually concatenated?

Comment: @tnknepp, adding index_col=None does solve the issue, date is no longer treated as the index so not sure what you mean

Comment: @Padraic, Sure, but the OP thought the index and first column were being concatenated into one column, which I was not able to reproduce.  If you were able to reproduce that problem it would be very interesting.

Comment: @tnknepp, as far as I understood the problem the OP was suggesting they were mashed together visually not actually a column called `"date at"`